What are my options to re-clad this bay window?
I have a 1930s house, with a bay window that used to be rendered.  The render was removed because it was cracked and discoloured.

This is what it looked like before.

Before I re-render it (several have offered to use "silicone render"), I am exploring alternatives.  I have seen another similar house locally with what looks like a tiled bay (it's just about visible on the streetview photo).
Is this kind of finish possible?


Your title asks about a window, but that's not what your post is about. It's just about masonry coatings. I suggest a revision.

that depends on how you define "bay window"

Apologies if I've used the wrong term. Is there a standard name for the space between the upstairs and downstairs window on a bay?

Render appears to be the British term for a  stucco type finish. It is a water permeable finish as per https://www.labcwarranty.co.uk/technical-blog/tech-update-render-on-substrates

Curved walls are a feature of art-deco architecture. but if you don't have to follow that you can render it as panels with tiled cut-outs.
